# git stash apply results in the conflict - why?

Tags: git

I've just tried to unstash changes and git reported a conflict:

```
Auto-merging core/scaldi/modules.scala
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in core/scaldi/modules.scala
```

I'm curious as to why this conflict occurs, since I have no changes neither in working directory nor in the index:

```
git diff          #outputs nothing
git diff --cached #outputs nothing
git status        #outputs `nothing to commit, working directory clean`
```

Answer (score 3):

> 'm curious as to why this conflict occurs, since I have no changes neither in working directory nor in the index:

It's not enough.
Seems you stashed changes some commits ago.

Assume your tree looks like this:

```
A------B------C------D[master]
        \                
         stashed -------^ (stash apply)
         sources
```

So stashed file changes of `core/scaldi/modules.scala` conflicts with some changes in C or D.

Comment: thanks, how is determined whether stash will apply cleanly or not? in the same way as a 3-way merge? Can you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me.

Imagine you were working in branch `feature/abc`

1. Switch to `develop` branch. Fetch and Pull from `develop` branch.
2. Go back to `feature/abc` branch. Rebase `feature/abc` changes onto develop.
3. Apply stash again. It should work now.