# how stash is applied - is it merged

Tags: git

I've had a conflict during `stash apply`. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391899/git-stash-apply-results-in-the-conflict-why) my question I was told that clean directory is not enough for applying stash without conflicts. So in order to figure out why the conflict occured I need to know what process git goes through when applying a stash. I know that stash creates two commits so I may assume that applying a stash is, in fact, 3-way merging. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the apply step uses the internal merge machinery.  One way to get the stash to apply perfectly (guaranteed to be clean) is to turn the stash into a branch: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452

Comment: Thanks, your answer by the link is really comprehensive! Studying it second day to get a full grasp of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Stashing takes the dirty state of your working directory — that is, your modified tracked files and staged changes — and saves it on a stack of unfinished changes that you can reapply at any time.

Read more [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)